# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `label` of type `object` supplied to `Button`, expected `string`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

in my react app I got lots off warnings like this:

[image]

It probably returns from this:

```
<Button icon='save' type="submit" label={<T value="processes.new.save"/>} raised primary />
```

Is there a way to solve this issues?

Thanks

Language Chooser:

Bevore I changed the translating style it worked ..

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {loadTranslations, setLocale, syncTranslationWithStore, i18nReducer} 
from 'react-redux-i18n';

import {de} from '../locales/de';
import {en} from '../locales/en';
export const translationsObject = {
    de: de,
    en: en
};

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        i18n: i18nReducer
    }),
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
syncTranslationWithStore(store)
store.dispatch(loadTranslations(translationsObject));
store.dispatch(setLocale('de'));

function getLanguage() {
    const myState = store.getState();
    const local = myState.i18n.locale;
    return local;
}

class LanguageChooser extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <li><a className="fa fa-language fa-2x" onClick={this.changeLanguage} aria-hidden="true"></a></li>
            </div>
        );
    }
    changeLanguage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (getLanguage() === "de") {
            store.dispatch(setLocale('en'));
        } else {
            store.dispatch(setLocale('de'));
        }
    }
}

export default LanguageChooser;
```

Whats the Problem? I do not get errors

Comment: where does the `Button` come from?

Comment: React toolbox is Used

Comment: `propTypes` for label prop is a string, and you provided object.

Comment: What could bei a workaround?

Comment: You can use PropTypes.element

Comment: @Felix, what is `T`?

Comment: Why you pass the <T /> tag to the table of the Button? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: at the label? should I do <button></button> thats possible in this case. Same Issoues are with title attribute

Comment: <T> is for translation

Comment: I mean what library you're using? Can you show us how you `import` it?

Comment: Of course 'import T from "react-redux-i18n"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If for some reason, you cannot use the components, you can use the
>   I18n.t and I18n.l helpers instead:

```
var I18n = require('react-redux-i18n').I18n;

I18n.t('application.title'); // => returns 'Toffe app met i18n!' for locale 'nl'
```

This is your case, the "reason" you don't want to use components is because you need to pass the translated text as a `string` prop to `Button` component.

So, you might want something like:

```
import {I18n} from 'react-redux-i18n';
```

then

```
<Button icon='save' type="submit" label={ I18n.t('processes.new.save') } raised primary />
```

And the warning should go away.

Comment: Thanks I will try it tomorrow

Comment: That loocs good, bot do not work ... Got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 't' of undefined `

Comment: @Felix, even if you import it like this `import { I18n } from 'react-redux-i18n';`?

Comment: Ok that solves that warning problem, but now I have the problem that my language chooser not works ... (bevore it did) I added my code above

Comment: @Felix, can you create a jsfiddle in order to reproduce the problem?

Comment: never done a jsfidle with react. can I import react-redux-i18n  in jsfiddle?

Comment: translating works for german. but if I want to switch with the languagechooser code posted above it will not switch to english.

the if part in changeLanguage() is performed. But the text is not replaced with the english version